# Out of order loop in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, data-science

I'm confused by the declaration of states in the following code:

This runs perfectly, but in the declaration for states, how is the statement order correct? It seems you call f before you declare f.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
data_url = 'https://www.ssa.gov/oact/babynames/state/namesbystate.zip'
namesbystate_path = fetch_and_cache(data_url, 'namesbystate.zip')

import zipfile
zf = zipfile.ZipFile(namesbystate_path, 'r')

column_labels = ['State', 'Sex', 'Year', 'Name', 'Count']

def load_dataframe_from_zip(zf, f):
    with zf.open(f) as fh: 
        return pd.read_csv(fh, header=None, names=column_labels)

states = [
    load_dataframe_from_zip(zf, f)
    for f in sorted(zf.filelist, key=lambda x:x.filename) 
    if f.filename.endswith('.TXT')
]

baby_names = states[0]
for state_df in states[1:]:
    baby_names = pd.concat([baby_names, state_df])
baby_names = baby_names.reset_index().iloc[:, 1:]
```

Comment: Sorry, I do not get your question. Do you mean the list comprehension `states = [...]`? What's wrong with that?

Comment: The statement here: `load_dataframe_from_zip(zf, f)`. It seems to pass in f as an argument but f is not declared before this line.

Comment: That's perfectly fine in a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions). You have `f` later in `for f in ...`. If you don't define `f` later, the interpreter will throw an error.

Comment: Ah yes. `f` must be defined immediately after, correct?

Comment: In short, yes. List comprehensions follow a precise sintax, you can find it in the link above or in any tutorial